# How can I find the Q factor an LC circuit using LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, passive-networks, resonance, 13.56mhz

I've built a very simple LC circuit which models a air core copper wire loop antenna.  I got the circuit resonate at around my desired frequency i.e., 13.56 Mhz. Now I want to calculate the Q factor using LTspice using the graphs etc.

What I did is, I took the frequencies less than the 3dB to the resonating frequency then used the formula Q = f0 / BW i.e., Q = f0/ Fh - Fl. I got a Q factor of around 680 which seems to be very odd.

I did some reading and found that the above process should be done with the S11 parameter graph and not with the ones that come with the LTspice. I want to know how I can calculate the Q factor using LTspice.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any resistors. Are you sure you have modeled your antenna correctly?

Comment: Try using a much higher resolution scan and watch the peak in current sky-rocket.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit does not at all take into the account resistive losses in metal (can be surprisingly high due the skin effect) nor the actual working as an (maybe ineffective) antenna i.e. some losses are caused also because the antenna radiates energy to the space. LTSpice knows NOTHING of radiowaves and radiation. You must get an antenna theory book or an antenna handbook to find the radiation resistance of your antenna and what it means.

There probably is some assumed resistance in the part models to avoid division by zero errors, but they do not present at all the antenna itself. They only give the surprisingly high Q you have got. With ideal parts the calculation would stop at the resonance frequency to a division by zero or number range overflow error when the algorithm tries to make the equation solving iteration to converge, but no convergence can exist.

Comment: Yes, there is a 1mohm resistance within the inductor by default. If you override it to zero, the simulation will fail to run exactly as you point out.